# Group Table and Text shape Error in Powerpoint

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto

I was working on a PowerPoint addon which I tried to group all shapes (text, chart, table). But when I select the table and tried to Group it throws an error in VSTO. And I can't able to do it manually also. While searching on the internet I found that it's a restriction from the Microsoft end. Somebody help me how to resolve this. Is there any other workaround way to achieve the Grouping functionality with Table Object? Somebody help me, please.

Here is the code I tried in C# with VSTO.

```
string[] groupNames = new string[shapses.Count];
int index = 0;

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape shape in shapses)
        {
       
                groupNames[index] = shape.Name;
                index++;
        }

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape groupShape = targetSlide.Shapes.Range(groupNames).Group();
```

Comment: If you can't to do that manually, why do you think there is a way to do that programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

To group a table with anything else, you must first remove the shape lock that prohibits grouping. The default OOXML contains the following:

```
<p:cNvGraphicFramePr>
    <a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="1"/>
</p:cNvGraphicFramePr>
```

Edit that to:

```
<p:cNvGraphicFramePr/>
```

Then you'll be able to group the table.